# How can I sort array by values (DESC, Numeric) and keep non-numeric keys order?

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried many things but none worked, I am sure I am missing something simple.

Here is my array:

```
$array['Product1'] = 500;
$array['Product2'] = 1230;
$array['Product3'] = 432;
$array['Product4'] = 2000;
```

Here is the result I want please!

```
$array['Product4'] = 2000;
$array['Product2'] = 1230;
$array['Product1'] = 500;
$array['Product3'] = 432;
```

Tried natcasesort, array_reverse, asort, rsort, nothing seems to work. What I am missing here?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You're missing a description of how those attempted methods failed to work/

Answer (score 2):

You tried much, but not the right thing:

```
arsort($array);
```

For more information aout `arsort()` see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

Answer (score 0):

You probably want arsort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

```
$array = arsort($array);
```

There is a comparison of the array sorting types here: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

You can also pass sort_flags to arsort - there is a list here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php (and a link on the arsort link above)

You should end up with:

```
$array = arsort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
```